# Enviar todas os dados retornados no mesmo email

Tags: python

tenho a seguinte query:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT raddb.StockMinimo.Id, raddb.StockMinimo.Produto, Minimo, Quantidade FROM raddb.StockMinimo LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.StockProdutos ON raddb.StockProdutos.Id = raddb.StockMinimo.Id WHERE raddb.StockMinimo.Identificacao = '3' AND raddb.StockMinimo.Ativo = '1' AND Quantidade < Minimo AND Minimo > '0'")
myresult = cursor.fetchall()
```

Que retorna os seguintes dados;

> Id    Produto Minimo  Quantidade

> 93    Fita Adesiva 15mm Transparente (Unid.)  6   3

> 112   Lápis De Carvão Nº2 (Caixa C/ 12 Unidades)  10  6

> 160   Saca Agrafes Para Secretária (Unid) 3   1

Depois faço o `for` para retornar os resultados:

```
for linha in myresult:
 Produto = linha[1]
 Minimo = linha[2]
 Quantidade = linha[3]
```

Envio o email da seguinte forma:

```
texto        = 'Os seguinte produtos encontram-se com quantidade de stock igual ou inferior ao stock minimo. {} ({}) ({})'.format(
        Produto.encode("utf-8"), Quantidade, Minimo)
```

O problema é que envia email por cada linha que retorne da base de dados. Como retorna 3 linhas envia 3 emails. Pretendia enviar todas as linhas no mesmo email.

Código completo:

```
myresult = cursor.fetchall()

for linha in myresult:
 Produto = linha[1]
 Minimo = linha[2]
 Quantidade = linha[3]

 if Quantidade <= Minimo:
   remetente    = 'xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com'
   senha        = 'xxxxxxxxx'

   destinatario = ['xxxxxxxx@123.pt']
   assunto      = 'Stock Papelaria'
   texto        = 'Os seguinte produtos encontram-se com quantidade de stock igual ou inferior ao stock minimo. Produto: {} Quantidade: {} Minimo: {}'.format(
        Produto.encode("utf-8"), Quantidade, Minimo)

   msg = '\r\n'.join([
      'From: %s' % remetente,
      'To: %s' % destinatario,
      'Subject: %s' % assunto,
      '',
      '%s' % texto
   ])

   server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
   server.starttls()
   server.login(remetente,senha)
   server.sendmail(remetente, destinatario, msg)
   server.quit()
```

Comment: veja como concatenar strings

Comment: @Elton Nunes vi como cancatenar as strings e fiz desta forma: `teste = [Produto.encode("utf-8") + str(Quantidade) + str(Minimo)]`, mas continua a enviar na mesma os emails separados

Comment: @Elton Nunes e pretendia enviar todas as linhas retornadas na query num só email. Penso que o problema não está na concatenação

Comment: concatena com \n entre as linhas, vai transformar em uma string mas vai manter a quebra de linha, um duvida em qual momento vc esta enviando o email? a construção do seu script não esta claro para mim

Comment: @Elton Nunes adicionei o script completo à pergunta.

Comment: o codigo responsavel pelo envio do email esta dentro do loop, ele deveria esta fora

Comment: @Elton Nunes coloquei fora, agora só envia um email, mas só envia a última linha das que retornou. Tentei com esta concatenação `teste = [Produto.encode("utf-8") + str(Quantidade) + str(Minimo)]`, mas só envia no email a última linha

Comment: ai vc tem que trabalhar a logica da concatenização

Comment: @Elton Nunes pode colocar um exemplo, para eu entender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

de forma super simplificada

vc esta fazendo isso

```
for linha in banco
    if linha
        enviaEmail
```

vc deve fazer

```
variavel
for linha in banco
    if linha
        variavel concatena linha

enviaEmail
```